# Insert SQL statement is not working after checking against quantities from tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, insert

I created a sale table which Insert function does not work properly. It shows the error message

> Must declare the scalar variable "@iProductID"

at the statement

```
using (var sdRead = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader())
```

I am really stuck here. I also want to know how I can achieve for inserting `SaleID` with auto-increment without with any input field at the form. Every time I insert a new record, `SaleID` should be auto-generated and saved in the database.

My code below work like this. I checked available stocks from my `Product` table. If quantity order is greater than quantity from `Product` table, show error message.

Otherwise, proceed to inserting order information into `Sale` table. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int iQuantityDB;
        int iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(txtCustomerID.Text);
        int iProductID = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductID.Text);
        decimal dPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text);
        int iQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
        decimal dSubtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSubTotal.Text);
        decimal dGST = Convert.ToDecimal(txtGST.Text);
        decimal dTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text);

        string strConnectionString = @"Data Source = KK\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = JeanDB; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
        using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            string querySelectQuantity = @"Select Quantity from dbo.JeanProduct WHERE ProductID = @iProductID";
            using (var cmdOrder = new SqlCommand(querySelectQuantity, sqlconn))
            {
                using (var sdRead = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdRead.Read();
                    iQuantityDB = Convert.ToInt32(sdRead["Quantity"]);
                }
            }

            if (iQuantityDB > iQuantity)
            {
                string InsertQuery = @"INSERT INTO Sale(CustomerID, ProductID, Price, Quantity, Subtotal, GST, Total)VALUES(@iCustomerID, @iProductID, @dPrice, @iQuantity, @dSubtotal, @dGST, @Total)";
                using (var InsertCMD = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, sqlconn))
                {
                    InsertCMD.Connection = sqlconn;

                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iCustomerID", iCustomerID);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iProdcutID", iProductID);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dPrice", dPrice);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iQuantity", iQuantity);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dSubtotal", dSubtotal);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dGST", dGST);
                    InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dTotal", dTotal);
                    InsertCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    LoadDataonTable();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no more stock");

            }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: check spelling "iProdcutID",   in line `InsertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iProdcutID", iProductID);`

Comment: Corrected the error. Still showing the error message of Must declare the scalar variable "@iProductID" at the statement of "using (var sdRead = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader())"

Comment: You need to add the param (`cmdOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iProductID", iProductID)`) before calling the execute `using (var sdRead = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader())` because you're using a param in the SQL (`WHERE ProductID = @iProductID`) but haven't set a value for it.

Comment: The error changes to Total now. Its error shows like this "Must declare the scalar variable "@Total". Total is included in cmdOrder.Parameters......What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line `using (var sdRead = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader())` your SQL SELECT query is using a parameter - `WHERE ProductID = @iProductID` - but this hasn't been set. Hence the error message `Must declare the scalar variable "@iProductID"`

Just add `cmdOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iProductID", iProductID)` between defining the SQL and executing it, and that should clear that problem.

Moving on to the next one - you're using `AddWithValue("@dTotal"` but it's `@Total` in the SQL :)

Comment: thannk alot for your help.